# Were Grindelwald and Dumbledore love partners?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In a scene in the Crimes of Grindelwald,  Dumbledore responds to a question saying that "they were more than brothers". It's also shown how they make the bloodpact and I see some clues in that scene that kind of says they were in fact love partners. So my question is were they really love partners?

Comment: Read this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41282/did-j-k-rowling-always-consider-dumbledore-gay) on sister site: Yes they were a gay couple.

Comment: Yes... There is no need to put this here... just read the Deathly Hallows, and your awnser is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: Yes, Dumbledore is considered to be gay by J.K. Rowling, and yes, he had been in love with Grindlewald at the time of the bloodpact.

I'm going to steal [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41282/did-j-k-rowling-always-consider-dumbledore-gay) of Slytherincess from our sister site Science Fiction & Fantasy.

J.K. Rowling had answered the question about Dumbledore's love interest long before the fantastic beasts franchise started. As the franchise was (co)written by Rowling herself and is considered to be canon this answer still holds true:

J.K Rowling said in an event at [Carnegie Hall - 10.20.07 - Via The Leaky Cauldron](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more):

> **Q: Did Dumbledore, who believed in the prevailing power of love, ever fall in love himself?**
>
> **JKR**: My truthful answer to you... I always thought of Dumbledore as gay. ... **Dumbledore fell in love with Grindelwald**, and that that added to his horror when Grindelwald showed himself to be what he was. To an extent, do we say it excused Dumbledore a little more because falling in love can blind us to an extent? But, he met someone as brilliant as he was, and rather like Bellatrix he was very drawn to this brilliant person, and horribly, terribly let down by him. Yeah, that's how i always saw Dumbledore.

Side note: If Slytherincess decides to answer here as well I will of course retract my answer as I do not want to gather points from someone elses efforts.